# When a guest program requires a memory not allocated, which should be triggered first, guest OS page fault or host EPT violation?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine, kvm

I'm wondering about this question. If I start a guest OS in kvm with EPT paging enabled, when the guest OS program first requires the memory, which should be triggerd first, guest OS page fault or EPT violation?

In my opinion, the value in gurst OS CR3 is a guest physical address. If guest OS wants to translate its virtual address, it will visit its page table pointed by CR3. At this time the EPT will translate the guest physical address in CR3 to host physical to access the guest page table. If there don't have corresponding entries, it will cause a VM-Exit by EPT-violation before guest OS page fault. When kvm enter guest OS next time, a page fault will be triggered.

I have no idea whether my thought is right or not, could someone help me about it.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: This looks like it may be helpful: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/EPT-protection-settings-for-different-pages-in-the-user-process-Code-pages-refer-to-both_fig1_272029327#:~:text=Extended%20Page%20Tables%20(EPT)%20mechanism,second%20layer%20of%20address%20translation.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! I have read the topic but I still have questions. In the topic. It says " In the first phase the CPU translates a guest virtual address (GVA) into a guest physical address (GPA), using paging structures inside the guest OS. In the second phase the CPU translates the resulted GPA into a host physical address (HPA), using the EPT. " My doubt is, in the first phase, guest OS translate the GVA to GPA by guest process page table. But the page table is stored in physical memory.

Comment: When I want to access the process's page table. I have to acquire a HPA, using memslots or EPT or something else. The graph just describe this phase as GVA->process page table->GPA. But I'm wondering would a EPT violation happen in this phase (finding the physical address of guest process page table), earlier than the guest OS find that there doesn't have corresponding entries and raise a #PF.

Comment: Or, In the first phase, the kvm access to the guest process page table(in physical memory) use memslot. The EPT is only used in the second phase(GPA -> HPA). I'm really confused about this.